# Passing parameters in jquery mobile popup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mobile, popup

OK, I've been struggling with trying to pass parameters from the page to the popup div (within the same page) using jquery mobile. I'd just like to be able to edit or items from the database within a popup.
Here's the array of items I'm trying to update:

```
            <div class="ui-block-c">
      <?php
        $fam_mem = $_db->rows('SELECT * from family_member', array());
        foreach($fam_mem as $f)
          {

    echo "<a href='?id=$f[member_ID]#edit_fam_mem' data-mini='true' data-theme='d' data-inline='true' data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' data-icon='gear' data-iconpos='notext'>Edit</a>";

    echo "<a href='?id=$f[member_ID]#delete_fam_mem' data-mini='true' data-theme='d' data-inline='true' data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext'>Delete</a>";
          }
      ?>
    </div> <!--End ui-block-c-->
```

Here's the code for the popup div:

```
            <div data-role="popup" id="delete_fam_mem" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content" style="max-width:340px;">
      <?php //include_once("./delete_fam_mem.php");?>
    <h3>Delete Family Member</h3>
    <?php
    echo "id is ", $_GET[id]; exit;
        $del = $_db->query("DELETE FROM family_member WHERE member_ID = ", array($_GET[id]));
        if ( $del )
        echo "Chore $_GET[title] deleted successfully.";
        else "Could not be deleted, maybe you should go to counseling.";
    ?>
    <button class="button" onclick='closefancy()'>OK!</button>
    </div> <!--End Delete Family Member-->
```

Some reason it will not pass the id from the page to popup. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just submitted a proposal which suggests how one could take parameters from the `opener`-button into the popups `beforeposition` event, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7136

Answer (score -1):

Put in your  tag id property. Like 'id'.
And put one element to recive the value in your page. Like:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="recivedId" />
```

So you can do something like that using jquery:

```
$('#a').on('click',function(){
   $('#recivedId').val($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestions didn't work me. When linking to a popup, jquery mobile uses hashes and the php will quit reading anything after the hash. Therefore, I changed my design to a dialog instead of a popup and that seemed to work just fine. Thanks for the suggestions! :-)